# Fundamental Group of complex Grassmannian

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, grassmannian

How can we compute the fundamental group of complex Grassmannian Gr(k,n) using Van Kampen Theorem only?

I know it will be simply connected, so we better find two simply connected open sets which cover it with path connected intersection.

> How can I get hold of such open sets?

Comment: Is there a reason you are limited to using the van Kampen Theorem if you can already compute that $Gr(k,n)$ is simply connected?

Comment: Yes I have been asked to use that only. Actually I don't "know" it already. I know it's true for complex projective plane so that's why I'm guessing it's true in general.

Comment: It is true. Though van Kampen seems like a strange way to prove it. For instance can you even use this method to show that $\mathbb{C}P^n\cong Gr(1,n-1)$ is simply connected if $n>2$? (at least not without using some cellular methods). You would do well instead to learn a little bit about fibre bundles and give an elegant and easy solution to problem.

Comment: @Tyrone Which fiber bundles are you alluding to? The one with total space k-frames?

Comment: @ConnorMalin The principal $U_k$-bundle whose total space is the Stiefel manifold $V(k,n)$. It is Example 4.53 in Hatcher's book. Personally I'd be more comfortable identifying $Gr(k,n)=U_n/(U_k\times U_{n-k})$ and working directly with the obvious bundle there.